# Entire string in For loop, not just character by character

Tags: python, string, csv, for-loop

Using CSV writer, I am trying to write a list of strings to a file.

Each string should occupy a separate row.

```
sectionlist = ["cat", "dog", "frog"]
```

When I implement the following code:

```
with open('pdftable.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for i in sectionlist:
            writer.writerow(i)
```

I create

```
c,a,t
d,o,g
f,r,o,g
```

when I want

```
cat
dog
frog
```

Why does the `for` loop parse each character separately and how can I pass the entire string into `csv.writer` together so each can be written?

Comment: Calling your list "list" is a bad idea

Comment: How is `list` (don't use that name for your own variables) related to `sectionlist`?

Comment: The actual file is a list of demographic data that lends itself well to csv writing, because I want to be able to edit it in excel. If writing it as a text file is easier and accomplishes the same task, please let me know! thanks

Comment: Sorry for calling it list, it was originally called sectionlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is:

```
with open('pdftable.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i in sectionlist:
        writer.writerow([i]) # note the square brackets here
```

`writerow` treats its argument as an iterable, so if you pass a string, it will see it as if each character is one element in the row; however, you want the whole string to be an item, so you must enclose it in a list or a tuple.

PD: That said, if your particular case is not any more complex than what you are posting, you may not need `csv.writer` at all, as suggested by other answers.

Comment: Thanks! This was the easiest edit to make to my code! And you taught me something valuable :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you even need to use csv writer.

```
l = ["cat", "dog", "frog"]        # Don't name your variable list!
with open('pdftable.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    for word in l:
        csvfile.write(word + '\n')
```

Or as @GP89 suggested

```
with open('pdftable.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.writelines(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `i` represents a *string* (word), not a *list* (row). Strings are iterable sequences (of characters) as well in Python so the CSV function accepts the object it without error, even though the results are "strange".

Fix `sectionlist` such that it is a *list of lists of strings (rows)* so `i` will be a *list of strings*, wrap each word *in a list* when used as a `writerow` parameter, or simply don't use `writerow` which expects a *list of strings*.

Trivially, the following structure would be saved  correctly:

```
sectionlist = [
    ["cat", "meow"],
    ["dog"],
    ["frog", "hop", "pond"]
]
```